# cakePHP - how can i manipulate fields before query?

Tags: mysql, callback, cakephp-1.3

In my db there are several common columns (`name` and `type`). example: `notes`, `remarks`, etc..

I want to manipulate each and every query to return them formatted. continuing the example: replace in the query itself, each `/n/r` or `/n`, with `<br/>`.

The problem is: if I will add this filters in the `beforeFind()`, i will have to specify the fields for each and every query. pointless.

Doing so in the `afterFind()`, using `nl2br()` will be an overkill that will require unneeded resources, since this queries are less than 10% of all queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

beforeFind is definitely the wrong place, because there isn't any data returned yet.

in afterFind it would be possible, but not very wise.

Why not create a Helper and call it directly in the View?

`<?= $this->Helpername->methodname($input) ?>`

And because CakePHP solves most of your problems out of the box, have a look at the TextHelper::autoParagraph method!

[http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/text.html#TextHelper::autoParagraph](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/text.html#TextHelper%3a%3aautoParagraph)

`<?= $this->Text->autoParagraph($input) ?>`

Comment: 1) thanks. 2) Because i have too many pages and i want to avoid it. 3) I use cake 1.3

Comment: you can easily backport the functionality:

http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/source-class-TextHelper.html#233-254